# Mobile site for early blackberry browser. (BB devices with scroller)

Tags: blackberry, mobile, mobile-website

I am developing site for older blackberry devices with scroller.

I ve noticed that they do not support styles and background images from start, these needs to be enabled in options in default web browser.

Is there a way to force browser to enable these options? I am testing against bb 8300 device simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to require the BlackBerry browser to automatically enable Javascript programmatically.

Some newer models will pop up a dialog box asking the user if they would like to turn Javascript on if the browser detects that the page requires Javascript.

Unfortunately, even these newer models, while enabling things like CSS by default, still do not enable Javascript by default.

If it's to be enabled permanently, the user would need to set that option manually through the device settings.

I think, if you don't want to rely on the device hopefully popping up a dialog asking the user to enable Javascript for your site, that the best route would be to determine when a BlackBerry browser doesn't have Javascript enabled, and let the user know that your page needs it (perhaps also providing some instructions on how to enabled Javascript on their BlackBerry device).

Comment: i agree, i wouldnt even bother with older BB devices, it just client has major portion of their force on those older items, and its internal portal of some sort. so i guess old good plain text, links and images  : )